# How to get thick lines around windows via UI settings?

Tags: interface, customization, theme

When I saw a video on the Blender YouTube channel, I was attracted to one theme.

The theme is that there is a dark gray line between each window.

What changes do I have to make in the Theme Editing to get the same results as the attached image?

[image]

I changed all the colors of the interface to blue, but I didn't get the same results as the themes in YouTube videos.

[image]

Comment: I dropped a line to that guy, let's see if he answers or comments here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there its a regular default theme But with **user preferences>interface>line width**  set to Thick.

its useful on tablets like the surface pro where the small hires screen makes panel manipulation somewhat tricky. Hope that helps, Happy Blending.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I couldn't find it it seems it's new in 2.79: https://www.mail-archive.com/bf-blender-cvs@blender.org/msg85611.html